# Captcha doesn't refresh when I use jQuery's html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have created my own captcha and I insert this code to my page `<span class="capch"><img src="captcha.php" /></span>`.

Captcha.php generates a new string and stores it to $_SESSION. It's works perfectly, but when user inserts a wrong code I need to refresh this image. I do it like this: `$('.capch').html('<img src="captcha.php" />');`

Why it doesn't show a new code? It really should, shouldn't? Or I am missing something here?

Comment: Are you sure that the `.html()` call is executed? Is the image being served from the browser cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var _cb = new Date();
$('.capch').html('<img src="captcha.php?v='+_cb.getTime()+'" />')
```

I would add a `?v=2` as a cache buster, where "2" is an incremented number each time it is updated. Even though the image comes from a php file it could still get cached because of its headers

Comment: instead of needing to keep track of an incremented number, i would simply make it a random string.

Comment: `?v=<incremented number>` is not a good choice. If a few are generated, and the page is refreshed, the `?v=2` image will still be cached.

Comment: @zaphod yeah even better idea

Comment: @locrizak: wow, it works, interesting. Probably browser caches such things. I will just use `Math.floor(Math.random()*101)` for v value

Comment: @hey, great... I would use a timestamp, I updated my answer showing it